# how to fix a problem with radio input costumized with css?

Tags: css, input, radio-button

I am doing an input radio customized with everything I learned about it step by step.
When I click on the older/standard radio inputs (without hiding them yet) everything is fine, I click on the old radio buttons and the new customized respective is checked.
But when I click on the newly customized radio buttons, they don't work as supposed to be.

The problem is that when I click the 2nd and 3rd customized radio it checks the 1rst automatically. 
I really need your help because I don't know where I am failing. I already look from examples codes on the internet and it was exactly what I did so I don't really understand where is the problem that I should correct.

```css
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.radio__span {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #049372;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.radio:checked+.radio__span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: .8rem;
  height: .8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #049372;
}


/* .radio{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
} */
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">
    <label for="chk">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p>Frontend</p>
            </label>
    <label for="chk">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p> Backend</p>
            </label>
    <label for="chk">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p>Fullstack</p>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to click on the new radio buttons and be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because of your **for** attribute which is looking for an input with an Id named **chk**, as you have got all three checkboxes with the same ID, it is checking the first...

The following would work:

```css
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.radio__span {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #049372;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.radio:checked+.radio__span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: .8rem;
  height: .8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #049372;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">
    <label for="chk">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p>Frontend</p>
            </label>
    <label for="chk1">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk1">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p> Backend</p>
            </label>
    <label for="chk2">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk2">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p>Fullstack</p>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thak you so much for the response. it was so simple and I wasn´t looking at .

Answer (score 1):

IDs **must** be unique. Once fixed, you need to then update your label elements to point to the new IDs. Fix that and it works fine.

```css
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.radio__span {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #049372;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.radio:checked+.radio__span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: .8rem;
  height: .8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #049372;
}


/* .radio{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
} */
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">
    <label for="chk1">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk1">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p>Frontend</p>
            </label>
    <label for="chk2">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk2">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p> Backend</p>
            </label>
    <label for="chk3">
                <input type="radio" name="dev" class="radio" id="chk3">
                <span class="radio__span"></span>
                <p>Fullstack</p>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```